# Importing files in Emacs Lisp/Emacs configuration file in the same directory

Tags: emacs, elisp

I have a couple of emacs configuration files. I was going to consolidate them down into a common file and then a couple other files that import the common file. Then have their own functions. I was just going to have them all as .emacsCommon in my home folder but when I write:

```
(require '.emacsCommon)
```

it doesn't load the function. What is the right way to do this??

Cheers

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use 'load-file' to load a EmacsLisp file

`(load-file "./.emacsCommon")`

Answer (score 6):

If you want to use `require`, you should add `(provide 'foo)` at the end of a file named `foo.el`. If that file is on the `load-path`, you can then use `(require 'foo)` to load this file, and add the feature (`foo`) to the feature list. (The printname of `'foo`, the feature name, is used as a filename here.)

Since your filename has a leading dot, and doesn't end in `.el`, you should give the filename as an argument to require though:

```
(require 'foo ".foo")
```

Note, that you could also just use `load` or `load-file`.

Comment: This is mostly superfluous information if you just want to `load` the file, though.

Comment: Fair enough. But you can use things like `featurep`, files will not be loaded unnecessarily, and it seems a little tidier to me.